# Dynamically jQuery not posting add inputs of a form after the .append()

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

Excese me, I use appends add inputs , but post form is not add inputs data.

Please talk me, how can I do , Thank very much!

HTML code

```
<form class="form_a" action="test_a.php" method="POST" >
    <div class="language">
        <div class="append">

        </div>
        <button type="button" class="add">add Button</buttond>

        <input type="submit" value="click me submit form">
    </div>
</form>
```

Javascript code

```
$('.language .add').click(function(){
    $('.language .append').append(
        '<input name="language[]" class="form-control" value="test">'
    );
});
```

PHP code

```
<?php
  print_r($_POST);
?>
```

Comment: where is the posting code?

Comment: @guradio hi, <input type="submit" value="click"> is my submit

Answer (score -1, accepted):

First, you must use the correct jQuery selector to get the Submit button.

Next, you cannot have newlines in the code as you can in PHP -- you must escape any newlines:

```
$('.language .append').append(\
    '<input name="language[]" class="form-control" value="test">'\
);
```

```js
$('input[type=submit]').click(function(e){
  e.preventDefault();
  $('.language>.append').append('<input name="language[]" class="form-control" value="test">');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<form class="form_a" action="test_a" method="POST" >
  <div class="language">
    <div class="append">

    </div>
    <label class="add"></label>

    <input type="submit" value="click">
  </div>
</form>
```

---

Note: it is a great idea to use an ID attribute to trap the Submit button (you cannot, however, use the word `submit` as the ID). Something like:

```
<input id="btnSubmit" type="submit" value="click">


$('#btnSubmit').click(function(){
  $('.language>.append').append('<input name="language[]" class="form-control" value="test">');
});
```

*Note: the `e.preventDefault()` in the answer example snippet is to prevent the FORM element from doing its default thing and navigating away from the page before you get a chance to see the DOM change.*

Comment: Remove the `e.preventDefault()` and read the note at the bottom of my answer. *Is that the correct problem?*

Comment: Also, you might have to amend the `<form>` tag to fix the action= attribute: `action="test_a.php"`

Comment: sorry, is ok!  is sumbit working!    but  also  test_a.php is not receive language data...